# CSS/JQuery menu not functioning properily in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

So, i created toggleable overlay menu, tested it in all major browsers (even in Internet Explorer), and its working fine everywhere except in *Firefox*(tested in version 46)!

The problem is, when you toggle overlay by pressing "**MENU**" button, the "**CLOSE**" button in overlay is not appearing and user is stuck with open menu.
***This how it should look:***
[image: Intended Behaviour]
***This how it looks like***
[image]
So i am asking you for help, since i allready ran out of ideas.

*https://jsfiddle.net/fpgkzd2x/5/ - Fiddle with working code.*

### **HTML Code**

```
<header class="main-nav flex-vhcenter-parent">
    <div class="button ">
        <p>MENU</p>
    </div>
</header>
<nav class="overlay">
<header class="main-nav flex-vhcenter-parent">
    <div class="button ">
        <p>CLOSE</p>
    </div>
</header>

</nav>
```

### **SASS Code**

```
$menu-color: #3c948b;   


.flex-vhcenter-parent{
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}



/* Main Nav menu styles */


.button{
  transform: scale(1.3);
  transition: all 500ms;
}


.main-nav{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 500ms;
    z-index: 20;
    background-color: $menu-color;
    position: fixed;
    &.fixed{
      .button{
        transition: all 500ms;
        transform: scale(1);
      }
    }

}

header > div{
    width: 20%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.main-nav p{
    margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

/* Toggleable Overlay */
.overlay{
  z-index: 30;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.90;
  top: -100%;
  transition: top 100ms ease-out;
  .button{
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
  }
}

.opened{
  top: 0%;
  transition: top 100ms ease-out;
}
```

### **JQuery code for toggling**

```
overlay = $(".overlay");
$(".button").click(function(event){
    overlay.toggleClass("opened");
});
```

Comment: display:flex its not fully supported by Firefox

Comment: Does it looks like You expect? 
https://jsfiddle.net/fpgkzd2x/8/

Comment: @S.Greczyn Yep, tottaly fine, klooks like it was all about flexboxes.
 And by the way, where have you got info about buggy flexboxes in FF? I cant wind it on MDN nor in Caniuse.

Comment: i don't remember, but i had similar issue and i solved them by replacing display: flex;

Comment: @IdeaMan Every browser has some glitches with flexbox. (Sadly because it's a very nice layout technique). IE has the most. Info on [Flexbugs](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs).

Comment: Try to change .overlay{ z-index: 30;} to .overlay{ z-index: 19;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display flex its not fully supported by Firefox 
Does it looks like You expect?

```
    $menu-color: #3c948b;   



    .flex-vhcenter-parent{
      display: block;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }



    /* Main Nav menu styles */


    .button{
      transform: scale(1.3);
      transition: all 500ms;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }


    .main-nav{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        transition: all 500ms;
        z-index: 20;
        background-color: $menu-color;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        &.fixed{
          .button{
            margin: 0 auto;
            transition: all 500ms;
            transform: scale(1);
          }
        }

    }

    header > div{
      width: 20%;
      display: block;
      align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .main-nav p{
      margin: 0 auto;
      font-size: 1.5em;
    }

    /* Toggleable Overlay */
    .overlay{
      z-index: 30;
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #000;
      opacity: 0.90;
      top: -100%;
      transition: top 100ms ease-out;
      .button{
        margin: 0 auto;
        color: #fff;
      }
    }

    .opened{
      top: 0%;
      transition: top 100ms ease-out;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fpgkzd2x/8/